# Is there a way to make GraphicsPath.IsVisible faster?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void FindPoints()
        {
            GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
            int x, y, p, j, wdthHght;
            int bytes;
            byte[] rgbValuesWithClouds;
            byte[] rgbValuesWithoutClouds;
            IntPtr ptr;
            Rectangle rect;
            BitmapData bitmap_Data;

            Bitmap bmpWithClouds; //No memory is allocated
            Bitmap bmpWithoutClouds; //No memory is allocated

            gp.AddEllipse(new RectangleF(73, 72, 367, 367));

            //using the using statement, bmpWithClouds bitmap is automatically disposed at the end of statement. No memory leaks :)
            using (bmpWithClouds = new Bitmap(mymem))
            {
                rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpWithClouds.Width, bmpWithClouds.Height);
                wdthHght = bmpWithClouds.Width;

                //Lock bitmap to copy its color information fast
                bitmap_Data = bmpWithClouds.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmpWithClouds.PixelFormat);
                ptr = bitmap_Data.Scan0;
                bytes = bitmap_Data.Stride * bmpWithClouds.Height;

                rgbValuesWithClouds = new byte[bytes];

                //copy color information to rgbValues array
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValuesWithClouds, 0, bytes);
                //we are done copying so unlock bitmap. We dont need it anymore
                bmpWithClouds.UnlockBits(bitmap_Data);
            }

            //using the using statement, bmpWithClouds bitmap is automatically disposed at the end of statement. No memory leaks :)
            using (bmpWithoutClouds = new Bitmap(@"F:\Drive Backup\Samsung Galaxy S9\Danny Backup\Recovered data 02-10 18_32_36\1  (D) NTFS\C-Sharp\Weather Radar\WithoutClouds.bmp")) //24 bit bitmap
            {
                rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpWithoutClouds.Width, bmpWithoutClouds.Height);

                //Lock bitmap to copy its color information fast
                bitmap_Data = bmpWithoutClouds.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmpWithoutClouds.PixelFormat);
                ptr = bitmap_Data.Scan0;
                bytes = bitmap_Data.Stride * bmpWithoutClouds.Height;

                rgbValuesWithoutClouds = new byte[bytes];

                //copy color information to rgbValues array
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValuesWithoutClouds, 0, bytes);
                //we are done copying so unlock bitmap. We dont need it anymore
                bmpWithoutClouds.UnlockBits(bitmap_Data);
            }

            // Each position in these arrays, rgbValuesWithoutClouds and rgbValuesWithClouds, corresponds a color. eg
            // First pixel   Second pixel   Third pixel   Forth pixel .... // bitmaps
            //    B G R          B G R         B G R         B G R    .... // rgbValues arrays
            bmptest = new Bitmap(512, 512);
            cloudPoints = new List<Point>();

            for (y = 0; y < wdthHght; y++)
            {
                j = 0;
                for (x = 0; x < wdthHght; x++)
                {
                    p = y * wdthHght * 3 + j;

                    if (rgbValuesWithClouds[p] != rgbValuesWithoutClouds[p])
                    {
                        cloudPoints.Add(new Point(x, y));

                        if (graphicsPath.IsVisible(x, y))
                        {
                            bmptest.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Yellow);
                        }
                    }

                    j += 3;
                }
            }
            bmptest.Save(@"d:\bmptest1.bmp");
        }
```

this method is being called in paint event

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Green, 0, 0, pictureBox1.Width - 1, pictureBox1.Height - 1);

            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, 256, 0, 256, 512);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, 0, 256, 512, 256);

            FindPoints();
            DrawPieOnPicturebox(e.Graphics);
        }
```

i found that if i'm not using or removing the part :

```
if (graphicsPath.IsVisible(x, y))
```

it will working fast but then it will color the pixels in yellow at once and i want it to color the pixels in yellow only if the graphicsPath is visible which make the whole application working very slow.

this is where and how i'm using the graphicsPath

```
public void DrawPieOnPicturebox(Graphics myPieGraphic)
        {
            Color myPieColors = Color.FromArgb(150, Color.LightGreen);
            Size myPieSize = new Size((int)distanceFromCenterPixels, (int)distanceFromCenterPixels);
            Point myPieLocation = new Point((pictureBox1.Width - myPieSize.Width) / 2, (pictureBox1.Height - myPieSize.Height) / 2);
            DrawMyPie(myPiePercent, myPieColors, myPieGraphic, myPieLocation, myPieSize);
        }

        public void DrawMyPie(int myPiePerecent, Color myPieColor, Graphics myPieGraphic, Point
      myPieLocation, Size myPieSize)
        {
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(myPieColor))
            {
                myPieGraphic.FillPie(brush, new Rectangle(myPieLocation, myPieSize), Convert.ToSingle(myPiePerecent * 360 / 100), Convert.ToSingle(15 * 360 / 100));
            }

            myPieGraphic.DrawImage(bmptest, Point.Empty);
            graphicsPath.AddPie(new Rectangle(myPieLocation, myPieSize), Convert.ToSingle(myPiePerecent * 360 / 100), Convert.ToSingle(15 * 360 / 100));
        }
```

Comment: Did you write this code, or just some pieces of it? What is `mymem`? How can a GraphicsPath evaluate whether a shape contains a point, when you haven't added any shape? At least not in `FindPoints()`, where you apparently have declared a GraphicsPath object, but you're using another object -- This: `p = y * wdthHght * 3 + j;` is terrible. I may assume you're considering only 24bit images, but that not the way to step through the bitmap data -- Why are you setting the `SmoothingMode` twice, with different values? This code looks like a patchwork

Comment: The answer to the post title would be _by making it less complicated_ but that may not be feasible. Also: Are you sure it is the IsVisible and not the notoriously slow SetPixel that eats up the time?